# POST non latin data from Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, post, character-encoding

I post some data from Java to PHP:

```
    try {
        URL obj = new URL("http://myphpurl/insert.php");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod(POST_METHOD);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("title", "العربية");

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = 
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(params));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        LOG.debug("response {}", response);

        in.close();
        response = null;
        inputLine = null;
        conn.disconnect();
        conn = null;
        obj = null;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    private String getQuery(Map<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = params.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = it.next();

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pairs.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pairs.getValue(), "UTF-8"));

            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }

    return result.toString();
}
```

The insert.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
    $posttitle = $_POST["title"];
    echo "$posttitle";
    echo urldecode($posttitle);
?>
```

The echo show some gibbrish `Ù…Ù„ÙŠÙˆÙ†` instead of the actual title `العربية` .

This gibbrish is then inserted in a mysql database.

**Additionnal info:**

- The DATABASE is `utf8_general_ci` and does support arabic (when I manually update the post using phpMyAdmin it works).
- I added `UTF-8` in the `InputStreamReader` and `InputStreamWriter`, and I had the following behaviour:

  - Tomcat6 on windows, (PHP + mysql) on CentOS --> OK
  - Tomcat6 on CentOS , (PHP + mysql) on CentOS --> Not OK

**Additionnal infos 2**

- Posting using javascript works fine: The page responds with the right encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things that can go wrong with your code, and we can't test it. Also, I suggest using a full featured HTTP client instead of `URLConnection`. The list of what you should check:

- Pass the right source files encoding to `javac` (your test is hardcoded. Do you run the same binary or do you run the program from your IDE or anyway recompile on the deployment machine?)
- Use UTF-8 to encode the query string
- If your API uses the HTTP request body, check that both ends agree on the encoding, and/or use the Content-Type MIME header
- PHP has binary strings (the encoding must be given) so make sure you use the appropriate parameters when connecting to the database, and/or transcode accordingly
- When sending text from the PHP server, mind the encoding of the template and of the dynamic bits!

The number of moving parts is quite big. You should not debug via print/echo because that adds another level of transcoding. If possible, dump the raw text bytes and use a hex editor.

It's funny that Windows → Linux is ok, while Linux → Linux is not. You may want to check the locale on both CentOS machines (possibly running the operating system command from inside the target process - JVM and Apache)

Comment: I run it from eclipse + tomcat (in windows), and a maven packaged war in CentOS.

Comment: I added the contentType MIME type to the request body, but no param passes anymore (all empty) : `conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: I used javascript to test the same php file http://audiogag.net/preprod_files/submittest.html . It works fine as well, so it cannot be a PHP problem.

Comment: Again, check the locales on the CentOS machines. Also, don't add Javascript tests and the like; try to reduce the number of moving parts instead. Use Apache HTTP client, activate debugging log, and post both requests

Comment: I used Apache HTTP client and changed the mysqli_charset to UTF-8 inside the PHP and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CharsetEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) to reveal possible encoding exceptions.

```
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder();
encoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
```